# Undefined reference to typeinfo for Code Synthesis generated Class

Tags: c++, xml, polymorphism, substitution

I have an XSD Schema that utilizes substitutionGroups (polymorphic types).  The schema is used in Java and C++, Java and JAXB is easy and I'm not having any problems there.  I'm using Code Synthesis to generate C++ classes for the Schema and this is where I'm having trouble.

Command Line Arguments:

```
   xsdcxx cxx-tree \
   --namespace-map "http://"..."="csspap_xsd" \
   --hxx-suffix .hpp \
   --cxx-suffix .cpp \
   --generate-polymorphic \
   --polymorphic-type-all \
   --generate-serialization \
   --root-element-all \
   Schema.xsd
```

The base type is called 'MessageType' and there are 3 abstract types (RequestMessageType, ResponseMessageType, and UnsolicitedMessageType) that extend the base type. Several messages extend these types.  The one I'm playing with is SuccessResponeType which extends ResponseMessageType.

The point is to be able to pass around the Message as a MessageType.  I'm trying to determine what type of message is being handled.

Schema Snippet:

```
    <xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Root Level Message</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="MessageType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Represents a Request, Response, or Unsolicited Response Message</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ResponseMessageType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>All Response Message Types</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="MessageType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SuccessResponseType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ResponseMessageType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="SuccessResponse" type="SuccessResponseType" substitutionGroup="Message"/>
```

Inside the Schema.cpp file there is code that compares classes:

```
   const ::csspap_xsd::SuccessResponseType& s;
   if (typeid(::csspap_xsd::SuccessResponseType) == (typeid(s)) {
      // this is a SuccessResponseType
   }
```

So in theory I should be able to do something like this in my class to check the type of message being handled.

In my test class, I attempt to print out the typeinfo.name for the SuccessResponseType:

```
   #include <typeinfo>
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Schema.hpp"

   int main() {
      std::cout << "Schema SuccessResponseType name: " << typeid(csspap_xsd::SuccessResponseType).name << std::endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

But when I attempt to compile my test class, I get the message "undefined reference to 'typeinfo for csspap_xsd::SuccessResponseType'".

I've read over the arguments for xsdcxx several times... and have no idea what I may be missing and why I can't get the typeinfo for my schema classes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Ace

Comment: Looking through my past posts and found this.  The solution was simply to say SuccessResponse.exists().

Answer (score 0):

You're doing very basic error, you can't declare a reference without initialization in :

```
const ::csspap_xsd::SuccessResponseType& s;
```